# Can't do breadth-first search on a binary tree in Rust

Tags: rust, binary-tree

I've implemented a binary tree in Rust as a learning project but failed to transverse it to print the tree in a breadth-first search fashion.

The issue is that I can't reassign the search queue (`children`) because it's borrowed and doesn't live long enough.

https://gist.github.com/varshard/3874803cd035e27facb67c59e89c3c1c#file-binary_tree-rs-L39

How can I correct this?

```rust
use std::fmt::Display;

type Branch<'a, T> = Option<Box<Node<'a, T>>>;

struct Node<'a, T: PartialOrd + Display> {
    value: &'a T,
    left: Branch<'a, T>,
    right: Branch<'a, T>
}

impl<'a, T: PartialOrd + Display> Node<'a, T> {
    fn insert(&mut self, value: &'a T) {
        let target_node = if value > self.value { &mut self.right } else { &mut self.left };
        match target_node {
            Some(ref mut node) => node.insert(value),
            None => {
                let new_node = Node{ value: value, left: None, right: None};
                *target_node = Some(Box::new(new_node))
            }
        }
    }
    fn display(&'a self) {
        let mut children: Vec<Option<&Node<'a, T>>> = Vec::new();
        children.push(Some(self));

        while children.len() > 0 {
            for child in &children {
                match child {
                    Some(node) => {
                        print!("{} ", node.value);
                    },
                    None => {
                        print!(" ")
                    }
                }
            }
            println!("");
            // Error: children doesn't live long enough;
            children = self.to_vec(&children);
        }
    }
    fn to_vec(&self, nodes: &'a Vec<Option<&Node<'a, T>>>) -> Vec<Option<&Node<'a, T>>> {
        let mut children: Vec<Option<&Node<'a, T>>> = Vec::new();
        for node_option in nodes {
            match node_option {
                Some(node) => {
                    match &node.left {
                        Some(left) => {
                            children.push(Some(left));
                            match &node.right {
                                Some(right) => {
                                    children.push(Some(right));
                                },
                                None => {
                                    children.push(None);
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        None => {
                            children.push(None);
                            match &node.right {
                                Some(right) => {
                                    children.push(Some(right));
                                },
                                None => {
                                    children.push(None);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                None => {}
            }
        }

        children
    }
}

fn main() {
    let root_val = 5;
    let mut root = Node{ value: &root_val, left: None, right: None };
    root.insert(&3);
    root.insert(&4);
    root.insert(&1);
    root.insert(&6);

    root.display();
}
```

Comment: This might be a useful read: https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/

Comment: What exactly is `to_vec` supposed to do? Why does it take both a `Node` (`self`) and a vector of `Node`s?

Comment: It suppose to return a vector of children of nodes that are passed into it. Basically, an nodes on a deeper level. Idf I passed root node, then it will return nodes on level 2 of the tree. If I passed nodes on level 2, then it will return nodes on level 3. My bad, `&self` isn't necessary and should be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying my answer from [this reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/eh49ov/newbie_please_help_me_with_transversing_a_binary/fcg1bnq/):

There's a way to directly fix your problem, but I think there are better options for making the code easier to write and understand. For the direct fix, you can make some lifetime adjustments. Instead of

```
fn to_vec(&self, nodes: &'a Vec<Option<&Node<'a, T>>>) -> Vec<Option<&Node<'a, T>>> {
```

You need:

```
fn to_vec<'b>(&self, nodes: &Vec<Option<&'b Node<'a, T>>>) -> Vec<Option<&'b Node<'a, T>>>
```

What's the difference there? In the first case we're saying that `nodes` is a `&'a Vec`. That is, a borrow of a `Vec` that lives as long as the `value` references inside your tree. That's a long time to live, and it's what the compiler's getting angry about.

Now, if you just take the `'a` off of that `&Vec`, the compiler complains about something else:

```
   |
42 |     fn to_vec(&self, nodes: &Vec<Option<&Node<'a, T>>>) -> Vec<Option<&Node<'a, T>>> {
   |                                         ------------       -------------------------
   |                                         |
   |                                         this parameter and the return type are declared with different lifetimes...
...
76 |         children
   |         ^^^^^^^^ ...but data from `nodes` is returned here
```

Maybe this is the error that pushed you to put the `'a` on the `&Vec` in the first place. We need to solve it a different way. The important thing to understand here is that the return value doesn't contain references directly into the `nodes` vector, but it does contain copies of the `nodes` vector's contents, the `&Node` references. We need to tell the compiler that even though the `nodes` reference *doesn't* live very long, its contents *do* live longer. That's why we create the new lifetime `'b` in my fix above.

This is objectively very confusing. Personally, I prefer to avoid solving these tricky problems, by just keeping things alive longer instead of reasoning about exactly how long they live. The source of the difficulty is that we're destroying the `children` vector on line 39. If we were able to keep it around, and just keep emptying it and refilling it, Rust would give us a much easier time. Have you considered using a `std::collections::VecDeque` instead of a `Vec` here? You could construct it once outside of your while-loop, and then you could pass `&mut children` around, without worrying very much about its lifetime. I think a queue is usually the go-to data structure for a breadth-first traversal, with new children added to the back, and the traversal itself reading from the front.